# Wordpress custom plugin will display on post but will not print

Tags: wordpress, function, plugins, printing

Here is a simplified version of the plugin. It does what it is supposed to do.  It displays the modified time like `Modified: February 23, 2016`.

```
<?php
/**

 */
function modified_date($content) {
    $post = get_post();
    if (is_page()) {
    }
    else {
        $origdate = get_the_time();
        $moddate = get_the_modified_time();
        if ($origdate != $moddate) {
            echo '<div class="mod" style="line-height: 1.2em; position: relative; text-align: right;"><strong>Modified:</strong> ';
            echo the_modified_date();
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'modified_date');
?>
```

I have tried `add_action` and `add_shortcode` with adjustments.  Both displayed the modified date on the post, but not in print.

I have tried many plugins to print my post, but none pick up the modified time. The latest plugin, I have used `Print My Blog` displays everything I want to see in a print except the modified time.  The easiest `Print My Blog` configuration that works (again except for the modified time) is:

Print My Blog > Settings > Print Buttons > select Posts

Then Customize Buttons > select Print

Is there something that I am missing?  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Could be that the print plugins are using the variable `$content` to print and your date is not in this variable. You only `echo` it, instead you should add it to the variable by doing `$content .= '<div ... >' . the_modified_date() . '</div>';`

Comment: @ChrostipSchaejn, thank you for response!  It provided the direction I needed to seek to resolve this. My "fixed" code is below.  - Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
/**

 */
function modified_date($content) {
    if (is_singular('page')) {
        return $content;
    }
    else {
        $origdate = get_the_time();
        $moddate = get_the_modified_time();
        if ($origdate != $moddate) {
            $content = '<div class="mod" style="line-height: 1.2em; position: relative; text-align: right;"><strong>Modified:</strong> '. get_the_modified_date() .'</div>'.$content;
            return $content;
        }
    }
}
add_filter('the_content', 'modified_date');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware that in your function `if $origdate == $moddate` you are not returning anything and the page will be empty. It's better to `return $content` at the end of the function to make sure it returns a value.

```
<?php
function modified_date($content) {
    if( ! is_singular('page')) {
        $origdate = get_the_time();
        $moddate = get_the_modified_time();
        if ($origdate != $moddate) {
            $content = '<div class="mod" style="line-height: 1.2em; position: relative; text-align: right;"><strong>Modified:</strong> '. get_the_modified_date() .'</div>'.$content;
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'modified_date');
?>
```